# How can I construct this exponential function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

It is an exponentially decreasing function. Five points are known:

$f(0)=10$, $f(12)=8$, $f(24)=7$ $f(36)=6,5$, $f(48)=6$

I know how to construct an exponential function if I have two points, but I don't know how to create this function, or that such exponential functian even exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no exponentially decreasing function that goes through these five points exactly. This would be the case only if the function decreased by the same factor each time the argument increases by 12 -- but that would imply
$$ \frac{8}{10} = \frac{7}{8} = \frac{6.5}{7} = \frac{6}{6.5} $$
which it is easy to see is not the case.

In fact these fractions are (roughly) increasing from $0.8$ to $0.923$, so on a logarithmic plot your points will not define a straight line, but a visibly curved one. This makes it look doubtful that your data indeed come from an exponential decay. Perhaps another kind of function would be better?

If you're sure you want an exponential, the best you can do is fit a function that goes *near* each of these numbers.
There are various ways to go about that, depending on whether hitting some of the points closely is more important to you than others.